# What is this Grothendieck's Theory

Tags: galois-theory, covering-spaces, grothendieck-topologies

In his book *Fields and Galois Theory*, J.S. Milne remarks that (see p105):

For Grothendieck, the classification of field extensions by Galois groups, and the classification of covering spaces by fundamental groups, are two aspects of the **same theory**

I wonder what this **same theory** refers to. And I would be much appreciative if anyone could recommend some good references for beginners about this theory.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck%27s_Galois_theory